# Given any vector, Is there a way to tell if the vector acts as a basis for a spanned set?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, given $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$, is this a basis a for the space spanned by the vector set $\{v_1,v_2\}$? Where of course $b_1,b_2,v_1,v_2$ all are vectors with numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I will assume that $B$ in your question is a set consisting of two vectors, namely $b_1$ and $b_2.$

To see that your claim is not necessarily true, consider $v_1=(1,0),$ $v_2=(0,1),$ $b_1=(1,1),$ $b_2=(2,2)$. Then $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it is clear that $b_1$ and $b_2$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^2.$

To check if $b_1, b_2$ span the same space as $v_1, v_2$ you need to do the following:

- If $v_1, v_2$ are linearly dependent, then check if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are spanned by $v_1$ (or $v_2$). If they are, then $b_1$ and $b_2$ span the same space as $v_1$ and $v_2,$
- If $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent, then check if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$. If they are, then check if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are linearly independent. If they are, then $b_1$ and $b_2$ span the same space as $v_1$ and $v_2,$

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean, but in my problem I was given a b1 and b2 that arnt obviously diffrent from the v1 and v2. I'm trying to see if theres a way to see if maybe the b1 & b2 are some linear combanition of v1 & v2&

Comment: In what space are our vectors?

Answer (score 0):

If the set of vectors B={b1, b2} can be written as a linear combination of the V vectors, V={v1,v2} (and b1 is not a multiple of b2, and assuming that v1 and v2 are also not multiples, so that the dimension of the spanned space is in fact 2), then the B vectors will form a basis of the space that is spanned by the {v1,v2} vectors.

If the b and v vectors are two-dimensional, and are independent (i.e., are not multiples, so that they point in different directions), then ANY two such vectors will span the entire R2 space.  However a pair of independent vectors (v1 and v2) in 3-dimensions (or higher Rn space) cannot possibly span the entire Rn space.  However the B vectors will span the same sub-space as {v1, v2} if b1 and b2 are each linear combinations of {v1, v2} (and are "different" vectors, i.e., are not multiples of each other).

Answer (score 0):

Rank gives the number of linearly independent rows or columns of a matrix. 
So construct a matrix $A=[B\,\, V]=[b_1 \, b_2 \,v_1\, v_2]$ and calculate the rank of $A$. If the rank is 2, then $V$ is spanned by $B$. This assumes the rank of $B$ is equal to 2. This should work for any number of dimensions.